# Can't compile basic C++ program with TBB and lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, tbb

I tried to write a basic C++ program using TBB and lambda expression, but I can't compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <tbb/parallel_for.h>
#include <tbb/blocked_range.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;

void Foo(int number) {
    cout<<number<<endl;
}

void ParallelApplyFoo(int* a, size_t n) {
    parallel_for(blocked_range<size_t > (0, n),
            [ = ](const blocked_range<size_t>& r){
        for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i)
                Foo(a[i]);
        }
    );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num = 10;
    int* a = new int[num];
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        a[i] = i;
    ParallelApplyFoo(a,num);
    return 0;
}
```

And compiler messages:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)’:
main.cpp:25:9: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
main.cpp:26:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘parallel_for(tbb::blocked_range, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>)’
main.cpp:26:5: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:161:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&)
main.cpp:26:5: error: template argument for ‘template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&)’ uses local type ‘ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>’
main.cpp:26:5: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&)’
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:168:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, const tbb::simple_partitioner&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:168:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:175:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, const tbb::auto_partitioner&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:175:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:182:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, tbb::affinity_partitioner&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:182:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:190:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, const tbb::simple_partitioner&, tbb::task_group_context&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:190:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:197:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, const tbb::auto_partitioner&, tbb::task_group_context&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:197:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:204:6: note: template void tbb::parallel_for(const Range&, const Body&, tbb::affinity_partitioner&, tbb::task_group_context&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:204:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:248:6: note: template void tbb::strict_ppl::parallel_for(Index, Index, const Function&, tbb::task_group_context&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:248:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘Index’ (‘tbb::blocked_range’ and ‘ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>’)
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:235:6: note: template void tbb::strict_ppl::parallel_for(Index, Index, Index, const Function&, tbb::task_group_context&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:235:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘Index’ (‘tbb::blocked_range’ and ‘ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>’)
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:228:6: note: template void tbb::strict_ppl::parallel_for(Index, Index, const Function&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:228:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘Index’ (‘tbb::blocked_range’ and ‘ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>’)
In file included from main.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:215:6: note: template void tbb::strict_ppl::parallel_for(Index, Index, Index, const Function&)
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:215:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:26:5: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘Index’ (‘tbb::blocked_range’ and ‘ParallelApplyFoo(int*, size_t)::&)>’)
gmake[2]: *** [build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o] Error 1
```

I tried compiler flag "-std=c++11" and "-std=gnu++11" which outputs then:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11    -o dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/test build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, unsigned int)::{lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1}, tbb::auto_partitioner>::~start_for()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, unsigned int)::{lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1}, tbb::auto_partitioner>::~start_for()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, unsigned int)::{lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1}, tbb::auto_partitioner>::run(tbb::blocked_range const&, {lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1} const&, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, unsigned int)::{lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1} const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb5): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
main.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_root_with_context_proxy::free(tbb::task&) const'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::start_for, ParallelApplyFoo(int*, unsigned int)::{lambda(tbb::blocked_range const&)#1}, tbb::auto_partitioner>::execute()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x251): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x33d): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4b6): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_continuation_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e8): undefined reference to `tbb::internal::allocate_child_proxy::allocate(unsigned int) const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::is_group_execution_cancelled() const'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::flag_task::~flag_task()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD2Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD5Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::signal_task::~signal_task()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD2Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD5Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::signal_task::~signal_task()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD0Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskD0Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `tbb::interface6::internal::flag_task::~flag_task()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD0Ev[_ZN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskD0Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:(.rodata+0x20): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE[_ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE]+0x14): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:(.rodata._ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE[_ZTVN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE]+0x14): undefined reference to `tbb::task::note_affinity(unsigned short)'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE[_ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal11signal_taskE]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o:(.rodata._ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE[_ZTIN3tbb10interface68internal9flag_taskE]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for tbb::task'
```

I am using Fedora 18 (tbb and tbb-devel packages installed of course).

Anyone some ideas please? The code is copied from here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/03/parallel_for-is-easier-with-lambdas-intel-threading-building-blocks

Comment: `lambda expressions only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11` - what do you think about adding one of those compilation flags?

Comment: @zch i tried -std=c++11, but firstly it says that it is "enabled by default" and secondly there are many more and weird errors than without the flag

Comment: @kolage Then post *those* errors. Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: @kolage You forgot to link the libraries.

Comment: When you specify `-std=c++11`, be sure to also add `-stdlib=libc++` or else you won't be linking to the right standard libraries that support C++11.

Comment: @us2012 well on Linux libraries should be in standard include path or aren't they? I've installed them using package manager ...

Comment: @kolage But you have to tell the linker to use them, i.e. `-l<libraryname>`, whatever the right one is, maybe `-ltbb`?

Comment: @us2012 yes thanks, I've found the link before I read your comment... stupid mistake, I am little bit noob in this area :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it using -ltbb compiler flag, found here: http://goparallel.sourceforge.net/compiling-tbb-programs-and-examples-on-linux-ubuntu/. Anyway, thanks everyone for help :)